# How to use XSLT to get only certain rows and certain columns?

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I use XSLT to convert this XML file:

```
<file>
    <row>
        <cell></cell>
        <cell>(info...)</cell>
        <cell></cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>first name</cell>
        <cell>last name</cell>
        <cell>age</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Jim</cell>
        <cell>Smith</cell>
        <cell>34</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Roy</cell>
        <cell>Rogers</cell>
        <cell>22</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Hank</cell>
        <cell>Grandier</cell>
        <cell>23</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>(info...)</cell>
        <cell></cell>
        <cell>(info...)</cell>
    </row>

    <row>
        <cell>Sally</cell>
        <cell>Cloud</cell>
        <cell>26</cell>
    </row>

    <row>
        <cell>John</cell>
        <cell>Randall</cell>
        <cell>44</cell>
    </row>  

</file>
```

to this XML file:

```
<file>
    <row>
        <cell>Jim</cell>
        <cell>34</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Roy</cell>
        <cell>22</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Sally</cell>
        <cell>26</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>John</cell>
        <cell>44</cell>
    </row>  
</file>
```

Basically the rules are:

- only **first and third column** (first name and age)
- only rows within certain ranges, e.g. in the simple example above it would be **rows 3-5** and **rows 7-8** so I would assume I would need some kind of mapping table with this information in it

## Addendum

Here is my solution using MarcoS's tip about params:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

    <xsl:param name="range-1-begin"  select="3"/>
    <xsl:param name="range-1-end"  select="4"/>

    <xsl:param name="range-2-begin"  select="6"/>
    <xsl:param name="range-2-end"  select="7"/>

    <xsl:template match="file">
        <marco>
            <xsl:for-each select="row">
                <xsl:if test="(position() &gt;= $range-1-begin and position() &lt;= $range-1-end)
                    or (position() &gt;= $range-2-begin and position() &lt;= $range-2-end)">
                    <row>
                        <xsl:for-each select="cell">
                            <xsl:if test="position() = 1 or 
                                position() = 3">
                                <cell>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </cell>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </row>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </marco>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and simple solution that uses one of the most fundamental XSLT design patterns -- overriding the identity rule. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a possible solution (maybe not very elegant):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

    <xsl:template match="file">
        <file>
            <xsl:for-each select="row">
                <xsl:if test="(position() >= 3 and position() &lt; 5)
                    or (position() >= 7 and position() &lt;= 8)">
                    <row>
                        <xsl:for-each select="cell">
                            <xsl:if test="position() = 1 or 
                                position() = 3">
                                <cell>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </cell>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </row>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </file>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Essentially, you can use XPath `position()` function to select the ranges of `row` and `cell` elements that you want.

Comment: +1: If you don't have better criteria for selecting the rows/columns (e.g., helpful attributes on the cells or differentiated element names) that's what you have to do.

Comment: That works nicely, is there any way to put the 3,5,7,8 in a "mapping xml" or some other data store and read out of it with XSLT?

Comment: @Edward Tanguay: you could use `<xsl:param name="param-name-1"/>` and then inject parameters values from the code invoking the XSLT transformation. Such code could take the parameter values form wherever you want: a mapping.xml, a DB, a GUI, etc. For using the parameters in the XPath expression, just remember to prefix their name with the `$` sign, for example `(position() &gt;= $param-name-1`

Comment: @MarcoS: There is no need for enconding `>` character in attribute values. Positional test inside content template are only useful when **context list** position is important (push style, sorting), otherwise is more straightforward to use it in the selecting XPath expression. Finally: **"Brick" templates are awful**

Comment: @Alejandro: about `>` encoding: you're right: I've edited the XSL above. About "positional tests inside content template": you're also right. I wrote that this was not very elegant, but it was the quickest solution I came up with. Also, in this case I'm not sure how to use `position()` in a selecting XPath expresesion. Can you give a hint?

Comment: @MarcoS: Yes, you can check @Glauber Rocha's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a piece of XSLT that does what you describe.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="file">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row[(position()&gt;=3 and position()&lt;=5) or (position()&gt;=7 and position()&lt;=8)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="cell[position()=1 or position()=3]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="cell">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To select the rows you want in your output, I think I'd begin by marking them with an attribute which would be used as a filter.
In the code invoking the XSLT, you could do it using DOM methods just after loading the XML document and before applying the transformation. Eg to keep Jim Smith but discard Roy Rogers:

```
<row keep="-1">
    <cell>Jim</cell>
    <cell>Smith</cell>
    <cell>34</cell>
</row>
<row>
    <cell>Roy</cell>
    <cell>Rogers</cell>
    <cell>22</cell>
</row>
```

And change the line in the XSLT to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="row[@keep=-1]" />
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is probably the simplest and shortest solution**, also based on using and overriding the identity rule:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:params>
  <row-range start="3" end="5"/>
  <row-range start="7" end="8"/>
  <cell-positions>
   <pos>1</pos>
   <pos>3</pos>
  </cell-positions>
 </my:params>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "row[(not(position() >= document('')/*/my:params/row-range[1]/@start)
     or
       position() > document('')/*/my:params/row-range[1]/@end
       )
     and
      (not(position() >= document('')/*/my:params/row-range[2]/@start)
     or
       position() > document('')/*/my:params/row-range[2]/@end
       )
      ]
  "/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "cell[not(position()=document('')/*/my:params/cell-positions/*)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<file>
    <row>
        <cell></cell>
        <cell>(info...)</cell>
        <cell></cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>first name</cell>
        <cell>last name</cell>
        <cell>age</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Jim</cell>
        <cell>Smith</cell>
        <cell>34</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Roy</cell>
        <cell>Rogers</cell>
        <cell>22</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Hank</cell>
        <cell>Grandier</cell>
        <cell>23</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>(info...)</cell>
        <cell></cell>
        <cell>(info...)</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Sally</cell>
        <cell>Cloud</cell>
        <cell>26</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>John</cell>
        <cell>Randall</cell>
        <cell>44</cell>
    </row>
</file>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<file>
   <row>
      <cell>Jim</cell>
      <cell>34</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>Roy</cell>
      <cell>22</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>Hank</cell>
      <cell>23</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>Sally</cell>
      <cell>26</cell>
   </row>
   <row>
      <cell>John</cell>
      <cell>44</cell>
   </row>
</file>
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. Doing the validation inside content template, one could use a general `document('')/*/my:params/row-range[$vPosition >= @start and @end >= $vPosition]`