# Read xml file to capture the values from <value> tags

Tags: xslt, xsd

We have a requirement to read the xml file and capture the EmployeeName and EmailId values from  tags to create the output as xml file.
The first  tag always represents EmployeeName and 5th  tag always represents EmailId.

Need to capture the values present in the row/value....

The input xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset xmlns="http://developer.net.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!--
<dataset
    xmlns="http://developer.net.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://developer.net.com/schemas/xmldata/1/ xmldata.xsd"
>
-->
    <metadata>
        <item length="20" type="xs:string" name="EmployeeName"/>
        <item length="4" type="xs:string" name="Full/Part Time Code"/>
        <item type="xs:dateTime" name="Hire Date"/>
        <item type="xs:dateTime" name="Termination Date"/>
        <item length="30" type="xs:string" name="EmailID"/>
        <item length="30" type="xs:string" name="State"/>
       </metadata>
       <data>
          <row>
             <value>JOSEPH</value>
             <value>F</value>
             <value>1979-04-19T00:00:00</value>
             <value>2007-08-27T00:00:00</value>
             <value>joseph.Tim@gmail.com</value>
             <value>TX</value>
          </row>
          <row>
             <value>NANDY</value>
             <value>F</value>
             <value>1979-04-19T00:00:00</value>
             <value>2007-08-27T00:00:00</value>
             <value>Nandy123@gmailcom</value>
             <value>PA</value>
         </row>
       </data>
    </dataset>
```

The Expected Ouput as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:EMPLOYEEDETAILS xmlns:ns0="http://net.com/EmployeeDetails">
<Records>
<EmployeeName>JOSEPH</EmployeeName>
<EmailId>joseph.Tim@gmail.com</EmailId>
</Records>
<Records>
<EmployeeName>NANDY</EmployeeName>
<EmailId>Nandy123@gmailcom</EmailId>
</Records>
</ns0:EMPLOYEEDETAILS>
```

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: The input data are malformed, as the code highlighting shows.  In any case, we are not a coding service.  Present some evidence of a bona fide good faith effort to solve the problem yourself, and pose one or more questions about *specific* problems you encountered.

Comment: Hi John, we tried as per the code present in the url-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270568/how-to-use-xslt-to-get-only-certain-rows-and-certain-columns. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the XSLT below. *You need to make additional changes for matching namespaces according to the input XML and adding the root node `<EMPLOYEEDETAILS>` in the output*.

**EDIT:** XSLT solution updated to handle the namespace issue. Root node `<ns0:EMPLOYEEDETAILS>` included in the solution.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://developer.net.com/schemas/xmldata/1/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="param-name" select="1" />
    <xsl:param name="param-email" select="5" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ns0:EMPLOYEEDETAILS>
            <xsl:for-each select="//ns0:data/ns0:row">
                <Records>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns0:value">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="position() = $param-name">
                                <EmployeeName>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                </EmployeeName>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="position() = $param-email">
                                <EmailId>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                </EmailId>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Records>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ns0:EMPLOYEEDETAILS>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<ns0:EMPLOYEEDETAILS xmlns:ns0="http://developer.net.com/schemas/xmldata/1/">
    <Records>
        <EmployeeName>JOSEPH</EmployeeName>
        <EmailId>joseph.Tim@gmail.com</EmailId>
    </Records>
    <Records>
        <EmployeeName>NANDY</EmployeeName>
        <EmailId>Nandy123@gmailcom</EmailId>
    </Records>
</ns0:EMPLOYEEDETAILS>
```

Comment: Hi Aniket, we have tried the given code but the ouptut result is not as expected. using the online toolz.com to test the scenario.The output from the given xslt is:<?xml version="1.0"?>
JOSEPHF1979-04-19T00:00:002007-08-27T00:00:00joseph.Tim@gmail.comTXNANDYF1979-04-19T00:00:002007-08-27T00:00:00Nandy123@gmailcomPA

Comment: Not sure why you are getting the result as you have shown. Please refer to the [link](http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zDJ) to view the result for the posted answer. If there is still an issue, the optimized solution above can be modified a bit to get the expected output.

Comment: Hi Aniket, there is a namespace in the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset xmlns="http://developer.Net.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 which is causing the issue.

Comment: Solution has been updated to handle the namespace issue. I had mentioned in the solution that you need to handle the namespace changes by yourself. Your output does not show `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` and hence it has been ignored. Please check [xsltransform](http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zDJ/1) for the working solution.